# Java Multithreading Synchronized Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a code this way,

```
public int handle_refresh(Data mmsg) throws Exception {
        String custId = mmsg.getCustomerId();       
        CustomerThread t = custMap.get(mmsg.getCustomerId());
        if (t == null || !t.isAlive()) {
            t = (CustomerThread) context.getBean("custT");
            t.initThread(mmsg.getCustomerId(), mmsg.getCustomerId(), mmsg.getMessageBody());
            custSMap.put(mmsg.getCustomerId(), t);
            t.createBufferThread();
            t.start();
            t.initStreaming();
        }
        synchronized (t) {
            if (null != t) {
                ret = t.addSymbols(mmsg);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }


                        }
```

Here CustomerThread is checked in custMap,

Map custMap= new CustomerThread ();

**if thread is there in custMap**

1) then read spring appilcation context and get it. `t = (CustomerThread) context.getBean("custT");`

2) In initThread method set the name of the thread uniquely for each customer.  `t.initThread(mmsg.getCustomerId(), mmsg.getCustomerId(), mmsg.getMessageBody());`

3) then put the newly created thread in to map  `custMap.   custSMap.put(mmsg.getCustomerId(), t);`

4) then in createBufferThread data is setting into cache.. `t.createBufferThread();`

5) then start the thread newly and then get data from db.     `t.start();`

6) set the db connections

**if thread is not there in custMap**

1) `synchronized (t) .`

2) call `t.addSymbols()` method.

My questions are...

1) Here does the first if block executes only first time and if once thread is created always synchronized (t) is executed?

I mean all the above 1 to 6 steps in if block are executed only once?

2) then what does synchronized (t) does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that `sychronized (t)` is protecting the `addSymbols` method to make it thread-safe.  Calls to this method are adding symbols, I assume, to some data structure within the `t` thread.  It may be that other methods in that thread are `synchronized` which would mean that it would be locking on the `Thread` instance.  That's what `sychronized (t)` is doing here.

But this is an extremely ugly way of adding thread-safety.  The `addSymbols(...)` method should itself lock on a lock object or, if necessary, be a `synchronized` method.  A class should be responsible for it's own locking and *not* require the caller to do something.

Couple other comments about your code:

```
t = (CustomerThread) context.getBean("custT");
```

The above code seems to be getting a thread instance from Spring.  This is typically a singleton unless the "custT" bean is some sort of thread-factory.  If it is not a factory bean then you are going to be getting the same thread-object for each call to your `handle_refresh` method and reinitializing it.  This is most likely not what you want.

```
synchronized (t) {
    if (null != t) {
        ret = t.addSymbols(mmsg);
    }
}
```

If `t` was `null` then the `synchronized` line would throw a NPE.  You don't need the `null` check inside of `synchronized`.

```
CustomerThread t = custMap.get(mmsg.getCustomerId());
```

If the `handle_refresh(...)` method is called from multiple threads then you need to make sure that the `custMap` is properly synchronized as well.

Answer (score 0):

The if block should only execute once per customer ID. Notice this line of code in the if block:

```
custSMap.put(mmsg.getCustomerId(), t);
```

It populates the map, so the next time a search is done with that customerId, it will be found and the synchronized block will be executed.

The Synchronized block will call a method on t inside a mutex lock.